# bpf_map_lookup_elem not working when key is struct

Tags: c, linux, networking, maps, ebpf

I am creating an entry into the map of type BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH in one SEC in the program and trying to access that entry in another SEC. The key is defined as a struct.

```
struct map_key
{
    __u16 key_1;
    __u16 key_2;
}

struct map_value
{
    __u16 value_1;
    __u16 value_2;
}

struct
{
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH);
    __type(key, struct map_key);
    __type(value, struct map_value);
    __uint(max_entries, 1024);
} bpf_map SEC(".maps");

SEC("sec1")
int sec1_func(struct __sk_buff *skb)
{
    struct map_key key = {0}
    key.key1 = 10;
    key.key2 = 20;
    check = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&bpf_map, &key);
    if (check == NULL) {
        bpf_trace_printk("Trouble.", sizeof("Trouble"));
    }
}

SEC("sec2")
{
    struct map_key key = {0}
    key.key1 = 10;
    key.key2 = 20;

    struct map_value value = {0}
    value.value1 = 15
    value.value2 = 25

    bpf_map_update_elem(&map_key, &key, &value, BPF_NOEXIST);
}
```

sec2 is executed before sec1, so the map is definitely created before bpf_map_lookup_elem is called. But still, i'm getting null value returned from it when i call this function in sec1.

Comment: I suppose both programs (from `sec1` and `sec2`) load successfully? Did you check the contents of your map with `bpftool map dump <ref to map>` to see whether the update works as expected? Note: in `bpf_trace_printk("Trouble.", sizeof("Trouble"));`, your two strings aren't the same size (one has a period) so the format size you're passing is not correct.

Comment: 1. Both programs are definitely being loaded, I've checked that properly.
2. I checked the contents of the map, i can see that sec2 is updating the values of the map but not sec1.
3. The bpf_trace_printk thing, I just made a typo here, that's not the problem I guess.

Comment: Could be the way you load your programs, maybe. How do you do that? Are you sure the two of them point to the same map? You should be able to check with the `map_ids` referenced by the programs in `bpftool prog` output (e.g. `bpftool -j prog | jq '.[]|.name, .map_ids'`).

Comment: yeah the two of them were not pointing to the same map, so I found the solution in specifying the pinning of the map to object namespace by adding that field in map definition.

Answer (score 1):

So the fix is,

```
struct map_key
{
    __u16 key_1;
    __u16 key_2;
}

struct map_value
{
    __u16 value_1;
    __u16 value_2;
}

struct
{
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH);
    __type(key, struct map_key);
    __type(value, struct map_value);
    __uint(max_entries, 1024);
    __uint(pinning, 1);
} bpf_map SEC(".maps");

SEC("sec1")
int sec1_func(struct __sk_buff *skb)
{
    struct map_key key = {0}
    key.key1 = 10;
    key.key2 = 20;
    check = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&bpf_map, &key);
    if (check == NULL) {
        bpf_trace_printk("Trouble.", sizeof("Trouble"));
    }
}

SEC("sec2")
{
    struct map_key key = {0}
    key.key1 = 10;
    key.key2 = 20;

    struct map_value value = {0}
    value.value1 = 15
    value.value2 = 25

    bpf_map_update_elem(&map_key, &key, &value, BPF_NOEXIST);
}
```

The additional pin field allows me to use the map in different elf sections within the same object file.

Comment: This also depends on the tools you use for loading your programs. Some will process the two programs from the ELF object at the same time and should be able to reuse the same map directly, some other workflows will process in two steps and will not reuse the map unless you explicitly ask it too - as seems to be doing the case for you when pinning the map. Good to see you solved it!